# RMarkdown french accents/special characters

Tags: accents, characters, french, rmarkdown

I want to use the LaTeX syntax for writing french accents/special characters in RMarkdown, but it doesn't work. `\'{a}` for instance doesn't compile but is literally printed in the pdf document. So far I didn't encounter any problems using arbitrary LaTeX code in my RMD documents. Are there some special compiling options I have to set maybe? I'm using RStudio to edit and compile the document.

Minimal example:

```
---
header-includes:
   - \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   - \usepackage[french]{babel}
   - \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---

r\^{o}les apr\`{e}s cong\'{e}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why this happens is because Rmarkdown pass to LaTeX unchanged only what is recognized as LaTeX code as:

```
\begin{whatever} ... whatever... \end{whatever}
```

or

```
\whatever{whatever}
```

or  even

```
{\whatever whatever}
```

Where `\whatever` could be any name,  even a single letter, but not a  sign. So special characters with letters as `\H{o}` or  `\c{c}` are recognized as commands, but not  `\={o}` or `\~{o}`. I guess that this is because recognize signs as command names could complicate the recognition algorithm or produce undesired effects, o simply was an unexpected use case because:

- It is harder to write is this way.
- It is harder to read the source is this way.

Anyway, you can always include these specials characters in a recognizable latex environment:

```
\newcommand\latexcode[1]{#1}

\latexcode{r\^{o}les apr\`{e}s cong\'{e}}
```

But the more important is that even if a special command as `\^{o}` can be passed unchanged to LaTeX, it must be completely ignored when exported to HTML or Word, while `ô` is perfectly exportable to the three formats.

So, keep it simple, and use the keyboard to make composed characters as far as possible:

```
---
lang: fr
output:
  html_document: default
  pdf_document: default
---

rôle après congé
```